# How to rewrite js to java, (instanceof usage, replace overload)?

Tags: javascript, java

Let's say we have such function in js

```
this.add = function (x, y) {
        if (x instanceof Vector2d) {
            this.x += x.x;   
            this.y += x.y;
            return this;
        }
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
        return this;
    };
```

Do I have to overload that in java just like:

```
    public Vector2D add(Vector2D other) {
        this.x += other.x;
        this.y += other.y;
        return new Vector2D(this.x, this.y);
    }
    public Vector2D add(double number) {
        this.x += number;
        this.y += number;
        return new Vector2D(this.x, this.y);
    }
```

Or is there any better / smarter / compact way to do such things?

Comment: What do you mean by a "better way"? "Better" can mean many things.

Comment: You're modifying the object that is called with the method, and returning a new one, sure that is you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class Vector2D {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    //...

    public Vector2D add(Vector2D other) {
        this.x += other.x;
        this.y += other.y;
        return this;
    }
    public Vector2D add(double x, double y) {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
        return this;
    }

    //...
}
```

You can return `this` instead of creating a new `Vector2D` object every time you call the method, just like you have done in the js version.

But I feel this type of question is better suited to the code review community:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Returning itself allows chaining such as `myVector.add(aVector).add(2, 3).foo();`